# Reading float numbers from a file and storing them into an array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, file

I am trying to store some floating points numbers from a file into an array, in order to use them further. By now, I am testing my function to see if it stores something, but all I got in the output is an array with zero's. 
My file has many lines , with 200 numbers writen per line.
My question is how to load all that numbers from file into an array properly. Thank you !

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void LoadCoefs(const char* input, float output[], int size );
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    float* coefs;
    coefs = new float[200];
    LoadCoefs("CoefsFile", coefs, 200);
    for(int i=0; i<200;i++)
    {
        cout<< coefs[i] <<"\n";
    }
    delete [] coefs;
    return 0;
}

void LoadCoefs(const char* input, float output[], int size )
{

    ifstream inp;
    inp.open(input);
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        inp >> output[i] ;

    }
    inp.close();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my computer this works.
Have you checked your ifstream?

```
ifstream inp(input),
if (!inp) {
  std::cout << "Failed to open the file";
}
```

Another thing, use [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of C-style arrays and pointers.

Comment: This is strange, I put the condition to check if the file it opens too. But all I obtain in the output console is 200 values of zero.

Comment: Well, I am using Mac and XCode, and I am not quite familiar with his way to format text. But is not working with .txt files. I have tried a few days  ago (with another example) to leave the file without extension and it was ok.

Comment: Ok. Double checked my output console and the issue is from my file. Is failing on opening. The rest of 200 zeroes are from allocating dynamic memory of coef.

Answer (score 0):

I have found what was the problem.

1) I have replaced my relative path of file with the absolute path.

2) My numbers were separated by comma. After removing comma, my array loaded with numbers from my file.